# python3 lib installed but no binary?

Tags: ubuntu, python, libraries, docker

Default installation of dist Ubuntu 16.04 has `/usr/lib/python3` installed but nothing inside of `/usr/bin` nor `/usr/local/bin`.

Why would they include a lib folder with `python3` and `python2` without installing python? This is the Docker Ubuntu image if that has any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all of the installed packages which use `/usr/lib/python3` with this command:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3
```

If you run that command on your system, perhaps its output will provide insight into why that directory exists there. One one of my Ubuntu systems `/usr/lib/python3` contains only `dist-packages`, with files beneath `dist-packages` owned by a variety of packages. It's possible some packages on your system provide support for `python3` without requiring `python3` itself to be installed.